# allow negative and positive number in textbox vb

Tags: textbox

I have a question, I need in the keypress event in textbox, just enter the caracter (-) and number

example:   -540612 or 64346

the textbox allow negative and positive number

Comment: I think you should be using the NumericUpDown control instead of TextBox control. It's meant for exactly this purpose. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/numericupdown-control-overview-windows-forms

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Private Sub txtMonRenta_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtMonRenta.KeyPress
    If Not IsNumeric(e.KeyChar) AndAlso System.Convert.ToByte(e.KeyChar) <> 8 AndAlso Convert.ToByte(e.KeyChar) <> 45 Then
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

this work perflecty!!

Answer (score 1):

> allow negative and positive number in textbox vb

The problem with the accepted answer is that it will allow multiple inputs of `-`. For example

```
-1234-1234
----123----
```

[image]

[image]

To allow only positive and negative numbers with `backspace`, use this.

```
Private Sub txtMonRenta_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtMonRenta.KeyPress
    e.Handled = Not (Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) Or
                     Asc(e.KeyChar) = 8 Or
                    (Asc(e.KeyChar) = 45 And
                     sender.Text.IndexOf(e.KeyChar) = -1) And sender.Text.length = 0
                    )
End Sub
```

1. The `sender.Text.IndexOf(e.KeyChar) = -1` will ensure that the character is not repeated again.
2. `sender.Text.length = 0` will ensure that the character is only allowed at the begining and not in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of "answers" to this type of question and after reviewing many I found a simple and straight forward way to handle. Here is the sub I call:

```
  Private Sub txtNumOnly_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs, txtBox As TextBox)

  'If not backspace or acceptable char flush key
  If (Not e.KeyChar = ChrW(Keys.Back) And ("0123456789.-").IndexOf(e.KeyChar) = -1) Then
    e.Handled = True
  End If

  'Only one decimal allowed
  If (e.KeyChar = "." And txtBox.Text.ToCharArray().Count(Function(c) c = ".") > 0) Then
    e.Handled = True
  End If

  'Deal with selected text too.
  If txtBox.SelectionLength > 0 Then
    If txtBox.Text.Length <> txtBox.SelectionLength Then
      If e.KeyChar = "-" Then 
        e.Handled = True
        Exit Sub 'avoid other checks, we're done
      End If 'e.KeyChar = "-"
    Else ''txtBox.Text.Length <> txtBox.SelectionLength
      Exit Sub 'allow it, all text is replaced
    End If 'txtBox.Text.Length <> txtBox.SelectionLength
  End If 'txtBox.SelectionLength > 0

  'Only one minus allowed and must be first char
  If (e.KeyChar = "-" And txtBox.Text.ToCharArray().Count(Function(c) c = "-") > 0) Then
    e.Handled = True
  End If

  If e.KeyChar = "-" And txtBox.Text.Length > 0 Then
    e.Handled = True
  End If

End Sub
```

Now in the KeyPress Event handler for the text box:

```
  Private Sub txtDaysReview_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtDaysReview.KeyPress
    txtNumOnly_KeyPress(sender, e, txtDaysReview) '<==Adjust the txtDaysReview to reference the TextBox being checked
  End Sub
```